# Remove current input if not yyyy/mm/dd format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove input data if it is not match with `yyyy/mm/dd` format ! I tried with following but only remove letter and special character ...

eg.

> 20144                 -> must remove last 4 
>   2014//                -> must remove last / 
>   2014/01/123  -> must remove last 3

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
   console.log(this.value);
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[^(\d{4})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159602/regex-to-validate-date-mm-dd-yyyy-while-typing

Comment: Perhaps splitting the date on the slash(/), then dealing with the year, month, and day separately would be easier. For example, this.value.split('/')

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is actually quite simple, once you actually break down the logic of what you want. So, you want to coerce user input into a `YYYY/MM/DD` format. We can do this in a step-by-step manner:

1. Split the input's value by the `/` character. You now get an array.
2. We keep the first three elements of the array, which should correspond to `YYYY`, `MM`, and `DD` respectively. We will ignore whatever fragments that come after, since they aren't part of the valid date. This can be done using `.slice(0,3)` on the array.
3. Parse each individual part of the array:

   - At index of `0`, you have the year fragment. Use `.substring(0,4)` so that it is trimmed to 4 characters max
   - At index of `1` or `2`, you have the month/day fragment respectively. Use `.substring(0,2)` so that it is trimmed to 2 characters max
4. Join the resulting array back using `.join('/')`.
5. If the array contains empty elements, you will end up duplicated `//` in your string. Simply trim them away using regex, `.replace(/\/(\/)+/, '/')`

You will notice that in my logic I have not included padding numbers, e.g.
. converting days from `1` to `01`. You cannot do this when the user is inputting, because you never know if the user intends to type one or two digits. If you want this, you will have to reparse the input `onblur`, because that is when you know the user is done with the input.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  var valueParts = this.value.split('/');
  if (!valueParts.length) {
    return;
  }

  // Only keep the first 3 elements of array
  valueParts = valueParts.slice(0, 3);
  
  // Substring array (keep first 4 characters for year, and first 2 characters for month/day)
  var substringCounts = [4, 2, 2];
  substringCounts.forEach(function(substringCount, index) {
    // If index does not exist in array, skip it
    if (!valueParts[index])
      return;
      
    valueParts[index] = valueParts[index].substring(0, substringCount);
  });

  // Join remaining elements
  var parsedString = valueParts.join('/');

  // Trim extraneous slashes
  parsedString = parsedString.replace(/\/(\/)+/, '/');

  this.value = parsedString;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Note: if you want to pad the numbers, you will have to include the following logic, *on top of what has been mentioned above*:

```
// Pad numbers on blur
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  var valueParts = this.value.split('/');
  if (!valueParts.length) {
    return;
  }

  // Only keep the first 3 elements of array
  valueParts = valueParts.slice(0, 3);

  // Pad lengths (year to 4 digits, month to 2 digits, day to 2 digits)
  var padLengths = [4, 2, 2];
  padLengths.forEach(function(padLength, index) {
    // If index does not exist in array, skip it
    if (!valueParts[index])
      return;

    valueParts[index] = valueParts[index].padStart(padLength, '0');
  });

  // Join remaining elements
  var parsedString = valueParts.join('/');

  // Trim extraneous slashes
  parsedString = parsedString.replace(/\/(\/)+/, '/');

  this.value = parsedString;
});
```

With that in mind, if you want to combine the above two logic together, you can abstract the part dealing with "joining remaining elements" and "trim extraneous slashes". I have hidden the code snippet below, since it's very verbose and mostly contains the same logic as mentioned above:

```js
// Helper method: joins array using '/' and trims duplicated joining characters
function joinAndTrimSlashes(valueArray) {
  // Join remaining elements
  var parsedString = valueArray.join('/');

  // Trim extraneous slashes
  parsedString = parsedString.replace(/\/(\/)+/, '/');
  
  return parsedString;
}

$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  var valueParts = this.value.split('/');
  if (!valueParts.length)
    return;

  // Only keep the first 3 elements of array
  valueParts = valueParts.slice(0, 3);

  // Substring array (keep first 4 characters for year, and first 2 characters for month/day)
  var substringCounts = [4, 2, 2];
  substringCounts.forEach(function(substringCount, index) {
    // If index does not exist in array, skip it
    if (!valueParts[index])
      return;

    valueParts[index] = valueParts[index].substring(0, substringCount);
  });

  this.value = joinAndTrimSlashes(valueParts);
});

// Pad numbers on blur
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  var valueParts = this.value.split('/');
  if (!valueParts.length)
    return;

  // Only keep the first 3 elements of array
  valueParts = valueParts.slice(0, 3);

  // Pad lengths (year to 4 digits, month to 2 digits, day to 2 digits)
  var padLengths = [4, 2, 2];
  padLengths.forEach(function(padLength, index) {
    // If index does not exist in array, skip it
    if (!valueParts[index])
      return;

    valueParts[index] = valueParts[index].padStart(padLength, '0');
  });

  this.value = joinAndTrimSlashes(valueParts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I do think that pure regex is going to be very bad at solving this you can just do a manual pass like e.g.

```js
var good = '2013/01/01';
var bad1 = '20123/01/02';
var bad2 = '2011//01/03';
var bad3 = '2010/01/034';
var bad4 = '2009//01/045';
var bad5 = '20083//01/223';

var all = [ good, bad1, bad2, bad3, bad4, bad5 ];

function normalizeDate(dateString) {
   var currentValue = dateString.replace(/\/{2,}/g,'/'); //remove repeated /
   var parts = currentValue.split('/').map(function (value) {
       return value.replace(/\D/g, '0');
   });
   var newParts = [ 
      parts[0] ? parts[0].padEnd(4,'0').substring(0,4) : '2000' , 
      parts[1] ? parts[1].padStart(2, '0').substring(0,2) : '01',
      parts[2] ? parts[2].padStart(2, '0').substring(0,2) : '01'
   ];
   return newParts.join('/');
}

for (var i = 0;i < all.length;i++) {
   console.log(normalizeDate(all[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
   var validationRegex = new RegExp(/([12]\d{3}\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/);
   if(!validationRegex.test(this.value)){
     this.value = '';
   }
});
```

This will match only the format `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for your answer! I reference your answers and I can figure out to solve my desire .

`I believe there have much better solution so answer here if you guy have better one`

```js
 var format = ["number","number","number","number","slash","number","number","slash","number","number"];
    $("input").on("keyup", function() {
       if(this.value.length > format.length) {
         this.value = this.value.slice(0,format.length);
         return;
       }
       for(var i in this.value) {
          if(format[i] == "number") {
            if(!this.value[i].match(/[0-9]/)) {
              this.value = this.value.slice(0,i);
            }
          } else {
            if(this.value[i] != "/") {
              this.value = this.value.slice(0,i);
            }
          }
       }
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text">
```